# Differenciability of piecewise double variabled function (elevated cross)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$ \text{Let}\ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0, & xy \neq 0 \\
1, & xy = 0 
\end{cases}
$$

Since $f$ is constant everywhere the partial derivatives exist and are both zero: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$

Since the partial derivatives are both zero (constant) in $\mathbb R^2$ they are also continuous.

According to theorem, $f$ is differentiable throughout $\mathbb R^2$.

Where is the error in this proof? $f$ cannot be differentiable since it would have to be continuous as well, but it clearly has a discontinuity at $xy = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the sentence “Since $f$ is constant everywhere the partial derivatives exist and are both zero.” The function $f$ is clearly *not* constant. And, for instance, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,1)$ doesn't even exist.

All you can say is at those points at which $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is defined, it is $0$, and the same thing applies to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.